# How do I display a module in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla

Very simple question. I've written a module for joomla, But how do I get it to display on content pages? Every tutorial seems to gloss over this very simple issue. I can see it in the module manager and it installs properly.

Please Help!

**Edit clarification**

Comment: Could you clarify by "display" -- do you see it in the Module Manager page or not?

Comment: Yes, I do see it in the module manager along with my parameters etc. I just don't know how to make it display on content pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This for Joomla 1.5 and might be different for other versions of Joomla)

In the Module manager, open(Edit) your module.

- In the Details section:
- - Set the Enabled radio-button to true,
- - Select the Position you want to display it in. (This position must be specified in your template like such:  ).
- - Set the Access Level to public. (It will be displayed to everyone.)
- In the Menu assignment area
- - Select Menus: All (It will be displayed on all Pages.)
- Click on the Apply button.
- Now select in the Details area the order you want to display your module in.
- Click on the Save button.

The above steps should display your module on every page in the front end.
If does not you most properly need to fix bugs in your module.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's on your Module Manager page, make sure that it's enabled and that it's set to the appropriate access level (i.e. Public if you want it to be showed for everyone, Registered for registered users, etc.)  Edit those settings as necessary.

Then check the module's position setting -- that will correspond to a position as defined in your template with the code (where in this example "xyz" is the name of your position):

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="xyz" />
```

See also [this page](http://www.kksou.com/php-gtk2/Joomla/How-to-include-modules-in-Content-item-for-Joomla-1.5.x.php) and [this one](http://www.joomlaspan.com/general/include-any-module-within-content-in-joomla-15.php) for guides.